# Bootstrap dropdown menu show animation working but how to exit animation on dropdown menu hide

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, css-animations

I have put css animation dropdown menu which you can see here:

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
    -o-transition: all .2s linear;
    transition: all .2s linear;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container pt-5">
  <!-- Example row of columns -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

      <div class="dropdown mb-5">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-display="static" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown button</button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="btn-group dropleft dropdown mb-5">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-display="static" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropleft
  </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <!-- Dropdown menu links -->
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="btn-group dropright dropdown">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-display="static" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    DropRight
  </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <!-- Dropdown menu links -->
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On dropdown menu show animation is working as expected. But how to do exit animation when dropdown menu is hiding. I want to exit animation look like the reverse animation on dropdown menu show. Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to remove the animations from your css and make your `.dropdown-menu` `display: block !important` because it was a js to hide and show dropdown in bootstrap, for initially you have to make `transform: scale(0);` to `.dropdown-menu` and also apply `transition` to it and when you click on button the class `.show` added with the class `.dropdown-menu` now when show class appears make css `transform: scale(1);` for more understanding see the following snippet.

```css
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
  -o-transition: all .2s linear;
  transition: all .2s linear;
  display: block !important;
  transform: scale(0);
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu.show{
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container pt-5">
  <!-- Example row of columns -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

      <div class="dropdown mb-5">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-display="static" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown button</button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="btn-group dropleft dropdown mb-5">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-display="static" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropleft
  </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <!-- Dropdown menu links -->
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="btn-group dropright dropdown">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-display="static" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    DropRight
  </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <!-- Dropdown menu links -->
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It will happen b'coz of when we set `display:block` or `display:none` then our animation is not working.

You just need to set `transform: scale(0);` instead of `display:none`. Please review my styling for more information.

Let me know if you have a question about the same

Hope this help

```css
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
  -o-transition: all .2s linear;
  transition: all .2s linear;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu{  
  transform: scale(0);     
  opacity: 0; display:
  block !important;
 }
.dropdown-menu.show {
  display: block;
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
    -o-transition: all .2s linear;
    transition: all .2s linear;
  }
  to {
        -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
    -o-transition: all .2s linear;
    transition: all .2s linear;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container pt-5">
  <!-- Example row of columns -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

      <div class="dropdown mb-5">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-display="static" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown button</button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="btn-group dropleft dropdown mb-5">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-display="static" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropleft
  </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <!-- Dropdown menu links -->
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="btn-group dropright dropdown">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-display="static" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    DropRight
  </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <!-- Dropdown menu links -->
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: on page load why all animation are working on page load. do i need to change some css

Comment: i need the animation exactly what u have mentioned with only problem is on loading the page all dropdown menu animation are visible to the users

Comment: Yes you need to just remove opacity from your "@keyframes example", Hope it will help.